# Bookmarklet will not redirect

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am trying to make a bookmarklet that will log me into my canvas and goes to a zoom page after it has loaded

This is my code:

```
                               This will log in the user into canvas
                                             |
                                             V
javascript:void(location.href='https://pccsk12.instructure.com/login/saml');
setTimeout(()=>{void(location.href='https://pccsk12.instructure.com/courses/9645/external_tools/184');},10000);
                                             ^                                            
                                             |
                               This will switch to the zoom page after everything has loaded
```

But it doesn't work. It logs in but doesn't redirect after 10 seconds.
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Once you've redirected the browser to a new page, the script environment and DOM are all reset and thus your setTimeout is probably being wiped out and not executed. You should try changing the code inside `setTimeout` to do a `console.log("Hello, world!")` as further proof of what I said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you switch the page the first time with `location.href`, it navigates to the new page and unloads all the currently running Javascript, including the timeout. You could try opening the login page in a new tab with [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), so it doesn't overwrite the current tab. It would look something like this:

```js
javascript:(function(){
    var login = window.open('https://pccsk12.instructure.com/login/saml');
    setTimeout(() => {login.location.href = 'https://pccsk12.instructure.com/courses/9645/external_tools/184';}, 10000);
})();
```

Comment: It isn't working. It makes a new tab with the saml page then changes the page that the bookmarklet clicked on to the zoom page instead of the saml page.

Comment: That is the intent. If you don't like that, you can instead save the opened window to a variable then change the location of that window.

Comment: that was not my intent, can you update your answer?